# Deploying Python App to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am following the 'Getting Started on Heroku with Python' [LINK](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app)
When I execute the command:  git push heroku master, I get the follwong output:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\heroku_workspace\python-getting-started> git push heroku master
github --credentials get: github: command not found
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com':
Password for 'https://git.heroku.com':
github --credentials erase: github: command not found
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !       See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git#authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-river-71834.git/'
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Which Github account is used above - Heroku's default one or mine?
Can you help me resolve this issue?
Thx!

PS. Additional question: is this a good platfom and language to create machine learning apps?

Comment: Did you do what the error message tells you, ie run `heroku login`?

Comment: yes, more the once - not helping. I can login to heroku, but when I want to push it to git, I get the error above.